# Refidim/Rephidim an acronym?

Tags: sources-mekorot, commentaries

When searching for the meaning of the phrase ברפידם I found out that the commentators read this as an acronym. But I found different of these:
One says it's an acronym for *rafu yadeyhem* (or rifui yadayim ריפוי ידים)
Another it's an acronym for *rafu yedeyhem min Hamitzvot*
While others say its's *rafu yedeyhem mi'divrei Torah* or *min ha'Torah*

I'm looking for their sources and the reason for their differences

Answer (score 3):

The vast majority of commentators (e.g. Rashi, Chizkuni, Rabbeinu Bachya/Bechaye, Or Hachaim) use the term "Rafu Yedeihem Min Hatorah", which is found in Mechilata Derashbi, Mechilta Derabbi Yishmael, Tanchuma, and Yalkut Shimoni, all here (Shemos 17).  Keli Yakar to Shemos 17:8 notes that this is because they were lacking water at Refidim, and Torah is compared to water.

There are a few Midrashic texts which have either Mitzvos or Aveiros, but they do not seem to be quoted by commentators, or come from similar mainstream sources.

(See [this search](http://mg.alhatorah.org/Search?mode=basic&p=1&c=1&s=1&t=%D7%A8%D7%A4%D7%95%20%D7%99%D7%93%D7%99%D7%94%D7%9D&distance=1&inorder=1&en=0&notes=0) for some details on the above.)